# confuse in RIP(Routing information Protocol) which is distance vector routing protocol but both tells different things

Tags: networking, routes, router

why rip protocol find the that path which has less number of hope while it is a distance vector routing protocol which consider that path best which has shorter distance between source and destination.

i want to clear my concept and clear the confusion.